# how to ensure InSingletonScope using only one instance

Tags: c#, singleton, ninject

I want to have only one instance of foo in my code but with this configuration each time it create new instance and I checked every time it comes to constructor and I can't understand why.

```
public sealed class foo: Ifoo
    {
        public string Test { get; set; }
        public foo()
        {
            this.Test = "test";
        }
    }
```

my container is like this

```
public class DefaultNinjectModule : NinjectModule
{
      public override void Load()
    {
         this.Bind<foo>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
    }
}
```

Comment: are you requesting `foo` or `Ifoo` ? because your binding is only to `foo`

Comment: requesting foo every where

Comment: @bidva That seems a bit off.  There's no real benefit to binding to a concrete class AND incurring the overhead of DI (particularly Ninject's overhead) since you lose the ability to code to contract instead of concrete implementation.

Comment: @DavidL ok is it possible show me how can I make only one instance of foo? I need only one foo in my project how can i injected just one foo into other classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To tell Ninject to Bind  the class in a singleton scope:

```
kernel.Bind<foo>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
```

> This behaviour will only work for instances requested from
>   the **Kernel**.

In your case it is requested by the DefaultNinjectModule(`this`) & not the kernel.
Create Standard Kernel instance in your DefaultNinjectModule,

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.Bind<foo>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
```

check this link for reference & customization:
[Object scopes](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes)

Answer (score 0):

You should bind your interface to your class:

```
public override void Load()
{
    this.Bind<Ifoo>().To<foo>().InSingletonScope();
}
```

Then when you want foo you use:

```
kernel.Get<Ifoo>();
```

This will get you your single instance of foo.

Note: If you have a single instance class derived from IDisposable, you must dispose your single instance, Ninject doesn't do this for you. In your unload do:

```
public override void Unload()
{
    this.Kernel.Get<Ifoo>().Dispose();
    base.Unload();
}
```